# SQL Query - Can I compare using LEN in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select

I basically want to do this:

```
SELECT HasComments = CASE (LEN(Comments) > 1) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM TableName
```

In other words, return a boolean telling me whether the length of Comments is greater than 1.  This gives me a syntax error.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  HasComments = CASE WHEN LEN(Comments) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    TableName
```

Comment: So I had the compare in the wrong place.  Gotcha.  Thanks @Quassnoi!

Comment: In newer SQL versions this would simply be `SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Comments) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM TableName`

Comment: @Harvey: how is it different from what I wrote?

Comment: Semantically it's not, but yours just didn't work from me on MS SQL server v17.

Comment: @Harvey: what error message did it give?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to make Comments NULLable and check for that. Indexes could then be leveraged instead of the table-scan LEN() will cause.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `when` and `end`

```
SELECT HasComments = CASE WHEN (LEN(Comments) > 1) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no WHERE clause, you're most likely returning a column of data:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(Comments) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'HasComments'
FROM    TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer SQL versions:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Comments) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM TableName
```